# React craco tailwind postcss integration

Tags: reactjs, docker-compose, tailwind-css, postcss, craco

My project use craco to start/build, I wish to integrate tailwind postcss.
I have follow this tutorial https://dev.to/ryandunn/how-to-use-tailwind-with-create-react-app-and-postcss-with-no-hassle-2i09
But as a result, I am suffering with this error:
[image: error]

My config files looks like below:

craco.config.js  (this one looks like where problem lies, as I feel like the style may overriding craco style underneath, so it caused above error, but not 100% sure how to resolve this puzzl.)

```
module.exports = {
  style: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [
        require("tailwindcss")("./tailwind.config.js"),
        require("postcss-nested"),
        require("autoprefixer"),
      ],
    },
  },
```

[image: craco.config.js full version]

postcss.config.js

```
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        tailwindcss('./tailwind.js'),
        require('autoprefixer')
    ],
};
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    purge: ["./src/**/*.html", "./src/**/*.jsx", "./src/**/*.js", "./src/**/*.tx", "./src/**/*.tsx"],
    theme: {
        extend: {
          screens: {
            xs: { max: "400px" },
          },
        },
      },
  };
```

I am running the app from

```
docker-compose up
```

Any suggestions to fix the error and config?
Please advise with some code example
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using `postcss` instead of the `postcss-nested` plugin. I followed the same article to get Tailwind working with CRA. Remove the `require("postcss-nested"),` line and `yarn add postcss`

Answer (score 0):

You need to uninstall tailwindcss postcss and autoprefixer. Then re install them with these specific versions

```
npm install tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

I had the same issue! There is more info in this link. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#post-css-7-compatibility-build